# Model Binding with Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a `PagingInfo` class that I use to pass information to my controller for pagination functions:

```
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage);
```

The pagination buttons are rendered in my View via:

```
<div page-model="Model.PagingInfo" page-action="SearchResult" page-classes-enabled="true" page-class="btn" page-class-selected="btn-primary" class="btn-group pull-right m-1"></div>
```

as this incorporates a custom tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "page-model")]
    public class PageLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;

        public PageLinkTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory helperFactory)
        {
            urlHelperFactory = helperFactory;
        }

        [ViewContext]
        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        public PagingInfo PageModel { get; set; }

        public string PageAction { get; set; }

        public bool PageClassesEnabled { get; set; } = false;
        public string PageClass { get; set; }
        public string PageClassNormal { get; set; }
        public string PageClassSelected { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context,
                TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction,
                   new { listPage = i });
                if (PageClassesEnabled)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass(PageClass);
                    tag.AddCssClass(i == PageModel.CurrentPage
                        ? PageClassSelected : PageClassNormal);
                }
                tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
                result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
            }
            output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
```

Also within my View, I bind specific model elements needed to filter the items displayed for pagination such as

```
<input hidden asp-for="@Model.SearchTerms.FormID" class="form-control" />
```

This is all wrapped in `<form>` tags. However, when I click the pagination buttons, no model binding occurs.

I can get model binding to happen if I instead change the `<div>` tags to `<button>` tags, like below:

```
<button page-model="Model.PagingInfo" page-action="SearchResult" page-classes-enabled="true" page-class="btn" page-class-selected="btn-primary" class="btn-group pull-right m-1"></button>
```

However, this then messes up the pagination button display making it unusable (same goes for `<a>` tags). Is there a way to bind my model within a `<div>` element?